# Bouncing ground and voltage spikes (power supply and grounding issues)

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, ground, grounding

I am having an issue with voltage spikes and bouncing ground in my circuit.

Circuit is powered with 12V DC power supply. I am have two DC-DC converters:

- 4V output (power module based on TPS54331) 3A max, used for SIM800L board (shown below)
- 3.3V output (cheap mini360 power module (below)) 2A max, used for ESP32 microcontroller

[image: SIM800 board]
[image: Mini360 module]

[image: Circuit diagram]
Of course I have many sensors and other stuff in real circuit but I belive they are not really responsible for this issue.

The problem is very often (like 50%) when SIM800 is sending SMS (according to it's spec it can take up to 2A) my ESP32 microcontroller gets restarted even it's using
separate power source and both power sources have enougth power. I even tried to add additional high capacity 500uF capacitors close to SIM800 VCC to be sure that it has enought power supply but it didn't solve the issue.

- CH1 Yellow - ESP32 voltage (referenced to ESP32 GND
- CH2 Blue - SIM800 GND (referenced to ESP32 GND)

[image: Osciloscope output]

Couple of observations:

- If I connect SIM800 GND and 12V GND with some additional 1,5 mm2 cable it's more stable but I still see the spikes on osciloscope.
- If I connect SIM800 GND and ESP32 GND with additional 1,5mm2 cable I see less spikes but it's still restarting.

Photo of measurement setup:
[image: Measurement setup]

In order to minimize effect of long ground probe wires I tried also self made ground spring instead:
[image]

With ground spring on the probes spikes are around 1.2Vpp but they still exceed ESP32 rated voltage.
[image]

Schematic for 12V to 4V DC converter:
[image]

Scheamtic for 12V to 3.3V DC converter:
[image]

So I am using only small capacity SMD ceramic capacitors. Should I add some bigger ones?

I am using 2 layer PCB and don't have separate ground plane due to lack of space. For ground I have quite long  1.5mm track going through whole board. It first go to 3.3V DC regulator, then to 4V DC regulator, then to SIM800L and ESP32.

How I can get rid of this spikes and fix the circuit? Why I see them?

Comment: There are other components in this circuit like optocouplers connected to ESP32 pins, some digital sensors etc. But I don't belive  they are responsible for this as their current consumption is very low.

Comment: If you could provide a more complete diagram it would be helpful. And those scopings, Vpp seems a tad low..

Comment: What you see on the scope may not even be ground bounce. After all, you are probing a circuit with an RF transmitter within few centimeters of the probes, right?

Comment: Please show a photo of your measurement setup.

Comment: @Justme - For CH2 (blue) ground measurment probe was very close to the SIM800 circuit. However when I measured CH1 (voltage spikes on ESP32 VCC) probe was quite far away from SIM800 RF circuit (like 15 cm).

Comment: @MiNiMe - I will add more complete diagram soon. Regarding Vpp maximum which I saw during few measurments was around 2.1V. I think it's quite high as ESP32 operating range is between 2.3V – 3.6V. So with 2.1V Vpp this voltage range will be exceeded.

Comment: @winny - I've added my measurement setup in the post

Comment: What’s your decoupling situation look like before and after the voltage regulators? What does the layout look like in terms of ground and power planes?

Comment: @winny - I've updated post with some additional informations. Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Is there a ground plane? Have you tried extending the antennas away from the circuit? (And perhaps a ferrite bead or several on its cable)

Comment: Ground spring looks good, but you are measuring "in the air" by the input screw terminal. Measure straight across the capacitor C2 and C11.

Comment: What's your layout situation? How many layers? Which layers does what?